# Stuck on if condition (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I want to execute three or more delete statement only if the 'if' condition is met.

I have this query that get several rows and every single row has a column called `last_update_date`. Take a look:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ATTR         as CATEGORY,
       product_attr_val     as COD_CATEGORY,
       qer.last_update_date
  FROM qp_modifier qer
  JOIN qp_list qar ON qar.list_header_id = qer.list_header_id
 ORDER BY qer.last_update_date desc
```

I want to execute these 3 delete statements only if the `last_update_date`
from the above query is equal to the actual or in fact the previous
day.

```
  delete from TABLE_PRODUCTS where product_id like 'WAL%';
  delete from TABLE_PRODUCTS where item_code like 'MAS%';
  delete from TABLE_PRODUCTS where customer_class_code='K' and customer_number is null;
```

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
  select max (last_update_date)
  into v_date
  from  qp_modifier
```

and then write this statement:

```
  if v_date = sysdate  or v_date = sysdate - 1 then
      delete from TABLE_PRODUCTS where product_id like 'WAL%';
      delete from TABLE_PRODUCTS where item_code like 'MAS%';
      delete from TABLE_PRODUCTS where customer_class_code='K' and customer_number is null;
  end if;
```

But it does not make much sense to me.

How would you modify it?

Comment: Since the query you showed can potentially return more than one row, what row is the one, that provides the date to compare too? Is it really the maximum? What if there's a date lower than the maximum that satisfies the condition? Is that ignored in such a case?

Answer (score 2):

You would have *one* `delete` if you used `or`:

```
delete from TABLE_PRODUCTS
where product_id like 'WAL%' or
      item_code like 'MAS%' or
      customer_class_code = 'K' ;
```

Then you can include your additional existence condition:

```
delete from TABLE_PRODUCTS
where (product_id like 'WAL%' or
       item_code like 'MAS%' or
       customer_class_code = 'K'
      ) and
      (select max(qer.last_update_date)
       from qp_modifier qer join
            qp_list qar
            on qar.list_header_id = qer.list_header_id
      ) >= trunc(sysdate) - interval 1 day;
```

Comment: Hey dude.
Could you please explain to me how this statement works: >= trunc(sysdate) - interval 1 day;?

Comment: @Student_new . . . That checks that the maximum date returned by the subquery happened on or after yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

`max()` function is not needed. The **if** condition is met, provided there **exists** any row for the join query with the **qer.last_update_date** column value exceeding(or equals) the day before :

```
delete table_products
 where (    upper(product_id) like 'WAL%'
         or upper(item_code) like 'MAS%'
         or ( upper(customer_class_code) = 'K' and nvl(customer_number,0)=0 ) )         
   and exists (
               select 1
                 from qp_modifier qer
                 join qp_list qar on qar.list_header_id = qer.list_header_id
                where qer.last_update_date >= systimestamp - interval '1' day )
```

where it's proper to use `upper()` to include all the data matching the wildcards' patterns case-insensitively.

Comment: Dude, have you got any idea about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59446601/container-problem-after-inserting-row-in-a-table?

Comment: Hey dude, how are you? Can i ask you something: The TCA Api is throwing this error message: "The site must belong to the customer account". Have you got any idea which api and method is failing?

Comment: Dude, have you got  any idea about it?

Comment: hi @Student_new . unfortunately I don't have any idea.

Comment: Oh, okay buddy :)

Comment: Hey dude, how are you? Could you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940909/creating-json-and-editing-a-complex-query-oracle-11g