# Container problem after inserting row in a table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, apache-camel, containers

I have 2 different systems that are connected using a MIDDLEWARE: I am  connecting MAGENTO with a ERP so i have to map different information ,that's why i am using **mapping tables**. It is running

In my case i have to map information about agents;, that table is inside a MYSQL database and it is called AGENT_MAPPING_TABLE. **The problem is that everytime that i delete any of the different rows inside that table i have to stop the container and reset it, otherwise the process will not recognize the new row.**

I need to solve this but i do not understand whats going on.

Take a look:

```
private void initializeAgentCodeMailMapping() {
        agentCodeMailMapping.clear();
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = getSqlServerDataSource().getConnection();

            //Get all customers
            String sql = "SELECT agent_code, email FROM AGENT_MAPPING_TABLE";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                String agentCode = rs.getString(1);
                String agentMail = rs.getString(2);
                agentCodeMailMapping.put(agentCode, agentMail);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }finally {
            try {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close(); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error while closing the connection");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Apache Camel Route:**

```
<route id="getEmailByAgentCode">
    <from id="_from6" uri="direct:getEmailByAgentCode"/>
    <recipientList id="_recipientList4">
        <simple>sqlServer:select EMAIL from  AGENT_MAPPING_TABLE where AGENT_CODE=:#AGENT_CODE?outputType=SelectOne</simple>
    </recipientList>
    <setHeader headerName="AGENT_EMAIL" id="_setHeader16">
        <simple>${body}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <log id="_log9" message="Agent email readed '${body}'"/>
</route>
```

Again, the table AGENT_MAPPING_TABLE is inside a MYSQL database.. if i insert a new row inside that table but if i forget to reset the container the process will never take the new row. Why?

Is there exist any way to solve this? I'm pretty lost :/

Comment: A application is not aware of a database table. An application is aware of a datasaet. Thus when you delete a row the application won't know. This is standard behaviour

Comment: Thank you for replying!. Is it possible to solve this? I do not want to restart the container everytime a new row is inserted/deleted :(

Comment: Isn't it the `Dynamic Recipient List` pattern described [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/recipientList-eip.html#_dynamic_recipient_list)?

Comment: @ShellDragon hey dude, sorry.. what do you mean?

Comment: Thats's the documentation page for `Recipient List` EIP. The specific link I have pointed to, throws some ideas into how to make `recipientList` dynamic, by switching to a message header instead of a hard coded one (constructed when the route gets built).

Comment: @ShellDragon thanks for replying.. Buddy, i am still thinking about the sql part. I do not fully understand how it could be helpfull in my particular case :/

Comment: @ShellDragon first of all: what do you think it's wrong in my code?

Comment: 1. I see two units of code. first is a Java segment and second one A Camel Route in XML DSL. Are these related somehow? I don't see it.
2. In the XML DSL for a route, a `recipientList` is built. The `recipientList` will be constructed when the route starts. After that, if you change the underlying database tables, your route wouldn't care. Could you help me understand how these two segments are related?

Comment: @ShellDragon Got it: why if i restart the container the new information is read? How is this behaviour explained?

Comment: Dude, these 2 units of code are not related at all.. i wanted you to know where the table AGENT_MAPPING_TABLE was called. Do you get me?. You wrote this:  "The recipientList will be constructed when the route starts. After that, if you change the underlying database tables, your route wouldn't care"How can i change that behaviour? I want the process to care about the underlying database

Comment: Camel routes defined in any DSL(XML/Java..) are constructed only when the camel context starts up. That's why container restart would cause a reload from the data source. [Here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/RecipientListTest.java) is a test case that illustrates how to make `recipientList` dynamic. You'll see, it packs the information in the message, as a `recipientListHeader`.

Comment: In addition to it, if you have to query the DB to read this info, for every single message that goes to the route, it may be very expensive. You should somehow cache this.

Comment: Hey @ShellDragon,how are you, buddy?
Could you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696037/not-getting-the-newest-information-from-a-table-recipientlist