# Creating JSON and editing a complex query (oracle 11g)

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle11g

I have 4 different tables:

> table_price_product (contains information related to the products and
>   their price)
>
> table_price_list (contains the information related to the price list)
>
> prices_per_client (contains the information related to the prices for
>   the different clients given a specific product)
>
> clients (contains the information related to the clients)

This is my SQL FIDDLE: [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbe60)

I got this:

```
CUSTOMER_NUMBER  |  CUSTOMER_CLASS_CODE|    PRICE
(null)           |           A         |    29223
(null)           |           B         |    33223
112121           |           E         |    40340
119435           |           E         |    40340
```

Now, i want to obtain in a single query all the data related to the products and the clients, replace A,B,C etc with CLASS A, CLASS B, CLASS C respectively **but** if the customer_class_code is = 'E' i want to obtain the name from table **clients** AND finally, convert everything and get JSONs for every product. Take a look at this, somehow i would need to add column "PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS" and "groups" because i need those columns to generate the JSON.

```
SKU     |PRICE|PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS|groups|CLASS A|CLASS B|WALMART|SUPERMARKET
99342435|9999 |                  |      |29223  |33223  |40340  |40340
```

[image]

I would like to generate a JSON with that information:

> {"sku":"99342435","PRICE":"9999",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:[{"group":"CLASS
>   A", "PRICE":"29223"},{"group":"CLASS B",
>   "PRICE":"33223"},{"group":"WALMART","PRICE":"40340"},{"group":"SUPERMARKET",
>   "PRICE":"40340"}]};

Can you help me?

EDIT:

```
<Item SKU="99342435" Price="9999">
    <PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS>
        <CLIENT_PRICE>
            <Client>WALMART</Client>
            <Price>40340</Price>
            <Site>USSITE</Site>
        </CLIENT_PRICE>
        <CLIENT_PRICE>
            <Client>SUPERMARKET</Client>
            <Price>48343</Price>
            <Site>USSITE</Site>
        </CLIENT_PRICE>
        <CLIENT_PRICE>
            <Client>B</Client>
            <Price>33223</Price>
            <Site>USSITE</Site>
        </CLIENT_PRICE>
        <CLIENT_PRICE>
            <Client>A</Client>
            <Price>29223</Price>
            <Site>USSITE</Site>
        </CLIENT_PRICE>
    </PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can replace most of your code with the following query.  You may need to adjust the IN clause, which is a pain if you are changing the customer list a lot.  But this replicates your results:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code) AS IDENTIFIER, tpp.item_code, tpp.price AS ITEM_PRICE, ppc.price
      FROM table_price_list tpl
      INNER JOIN table_price_product tpp ON tpp.list_header_id = tpl.list_header_id AND tpp.request_id = tpl.request_id
      INNER JOIN prices_per_client ppc ON tpp.item_code = ppc.item_code
      LEFT JOIN clients c ON ppc.customer_number = c.account_number
      WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL(tpp.start_date_active, SYSDATE) AND NVL(tpp.end_date_active, SYSDATE+1))
PIVOT (AVG(PRICE) FOR IDENTIFIER IN ('A' AS CLASS_A , 'B' AS CLASS_B, 'SUPERMARKET' AS SUPERMARKET, 'WALMART' AS WALMART));
```

Here is an update [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e57ad6/23).

As for the JSON output, it would be much easier if you were on a later version as it is now part of the core functionality.

**EDIT: Adding XML Functionality per Comments**

You could check out this query:

```sql
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT
                    XMLELEMENT("Item",
                               XMLATTRIBUTES(sub.item_code AS "SKU", sub.item_price AS "Price"),
                               XMLELEMENT("PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS",
                                          XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("CLIENT_PRICE",
                                                            XMLFOREST(sub.identifier AS "Client", sub.price AS "Price"))))) AS CLOB INDENT)                                              
FROM (SELECT DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code) AS IDENTIFIER, tpp.item_code, tpp.price AS ITEM_PRICE, avg(ppc.price) AS PRICE
      FROM table_price_list tpl
      INNER JOIN table_price_product tpp ON tpp.list_header_id = tpl.list_header_id AND tpp.request_id = tpl.request_id
      INNER JOIN prices_per_client ppc ON tpp.item_code = ppc.item_code
      LEFT JOIN clients c ON ppc.customer_number = c.account_number
      WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL(tpp.start_date_active, SYSDATE) AND NVL(tpp.end_date_active, SYSDATE+1)
      GROUP BY DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code), tpp.item_code, tpp.price) sub
WHERE sub.identifier IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY sub.item_code, sub.item_price;
```

Here is an updated fiddle with that query ([Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e57ad6/44/0)).

Which produces the following output:

```xml
<Item SKU="99342435" Price="9999">
    <PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS>
        <CLIENT_PRICE>
            <Client>WALMART</Client>
            <Price>40340</Price>
        </CLIENT_PRICE>
        <CLIENT_PRICE>
            <Client>SUPERMARKET</Client>
            <Price>48343</Price>
        </CLIENT_PRICE>
        <CLIENT_PRICE>
            <Client>B</Client>
            <Price>33223</Price>
        </CLIENT_PRICE>
        <CLIENT_PRICE>
            <Client>A</Client>
            <Price>29223</Price>
        </CLIENT_PRICE>
    </PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS>
</Item>
```

**Edit 2: Adding JSON via String Concatination**

The following would output JSON via direct string concatination:

```sql
SELECT '{"sku":"'||sub.item_code||'","PRICE":"'||sub.item_price||'",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:['||listagg('{"group":"'||sub.identifier||'","PRICE":"'||sub.price||'"}',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sub.identifier)||']};' AS JSON                                              
FROM (SELECT DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code) AS IDENTIFIER, tpp.item_code, replace(tpp.price, ',', '.') AS ITEM_PRICE, REPLACE(avg(ppc.price), ',', '.') AS PRICE, 
      tpl.request_id, max(tpl.request_id) over (partition by tpp.item_code) as max_request
      FROM table_price_list tpl
      INNER JOIN table_price_product tpp ON tpp.list_header_id = tpl.list_header_id AND tpp.request_id = tpl.request_id
      INNER JOIN prices_per_client ppc ON tpp.item_code = ppc.item_code
      LEFT JOIN clients c ON ppc.customer_number = c.account_number
      WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL(tpp.start_date_active, SYSDATE) AND NVL(tpp.end_date_active, SYSDATE+1)
      GROUP BY DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code), tpp.item_code, tpp.price, tpl.request_id) sub 
WHERE sub.identifier IS NOT NULL
and sub.request_id = sub.max_request
GROUP BY sub.item_code, sub.item_price;
```

And an updated fiddle with this query ([Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e57ad6/57/0))

**Edit 3: Added Replace**
**Edit 4: Added analytical function **

Comment: Hey dude, thank you for replying!. Gonna check it out :)

Comment: Dude, how would you do to generate a JSON from that query? I would need to generate 2 new fields: PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS and group. I need to get this output somehow: {"sku":"99342435","PRICE":"9999",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:[{"group":"CLASS A", "PRICE":"29223"},{"group":"CLASS B", "PRICE":"33223"},{"group":"WALMART","PRICE":"40340"},{"group":"SUPERMARKET", "PRICE":"40340"}]};

Comment: @Student_new To be honest, I'm not sure.  Since you are on 11g, I might try XML instead of JSON.  You could look into the XMLELEMENT, XMLAGG and XMLFOREST functions to replicate your JSON output.   If you just need the empty columns, you can just modify the "SELECT *" to call the actual column names and just add two empty columns.

Comment: Yeah, i'm checking it out :D.. honestly i was looking for a JSON output instead of a XML one.. that's a tricky part:. Just a question: how would to do to add this in the XML format: <Site>USSITE</Site>? Take a look at my thread, i have updated my question

Comment: @Student_new Is the site value hardcoded or pulled from a table? I don't see it in your schema.  If it is hard coded, then just add `'USSITE' AS "Site"` to the XMLFOREST.  If you really need JSON, you could just force it via string concatination.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Student_new One problem with using LISTAGG in 11g is that you can quickly run up against the maximum string length, which is why I prefer XML.

Comment: Yeah, i also heard LISTAGG was not very useful at all but i have no other idea :(. Dude, one thing: it is displaying "group":"A", "group":"B" and so on but in that cases i would like to display "group":"Class A", "group":"Class B". How do you change that? I think my brain needs a break.. I cannot make it work without the "_".. it works if i use Class_A or Class_B but i want to do that without the "_A", do you get me?

Comment: @Student_new Just modify the else branch of the DECODE statement to say `'Class '||ppc.customer_class_code` instead of just `ppc.customer_class_code`

Comment: Alright, pal!. The last question before closing the thread :). Imagine that some prices from table *prices_per_client* or even the table *table_price_product* have a "," i.e: 457,54 or 784,21, right? How would you do to convert that comma into a point ".", i mean: 457.54 or 784.21? What's the function that can do that?How can i forcé that convertion?

Comment: @Student_new Assuming that you never had commas in there as thousands separators, I would use the [replace function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions153.htm#SQLRF00697)

Comment: Is it possible to apply REPLACE function in your query?

Comment: @Student_new Dude, you're lucky you caught me on a super slow day.  I added the replace into the last JSON query.  I added it to both price fields.

Comment: You really made me to use my head today!, Dude, can i ask you the LAST question: i was trying to modify your query a little bit; the problem with your query is that you are retrieving the information of all products from table *table_price_product* (duplicates are allowed in the code) but i want to get only the products within the latest request_id for each product. Do note that the request_id may not be the same in every product, I only want to obtain the latest product with the highest request_id. Something like this: request_id = (select max(request_id) from table_price_product a where

Comment: request_id = (select max(request_id) from table_price_product b where a.item_code =b.item_code…. this is an example, do you  get me? I was not able to do that in your query :/

Comment: @Student_new Check out the analytical function that I added, it should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, buddy :)

Comment: Dude, how are you?
Could you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065300/hard-coding-values-in-sql-complex-query

Comment: Ar you there, buddy?