# Hard-coding values in SQL (complex query)

Tags: sql

Take a look at this SQL FIDDLE: [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e57ad6/58)

There exist a table called "clients" that contains information related to clients:

> The relation is "account number" - "client name"

and i used this sentence in order to obtain the name of the client:

> LEFT JOIN clients c ON ppc.customer_number = c.account_number

I do not want to join the table **clients** anymore, but i want to obtain the same result, do you get me?.

I mean, i need this output:

> {"sku":"99342435","PRICE":"9999",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:[{"group":"A","PRICE":"29223"},{"group":"B","PRICE":"33223"},{"group":"SUPERMARKET","PRICE":"48343"},{"group":"WALMART","PRICE":"40340"}]};

Somehow i would need to hard-code the values related to the account_number, i.e:

> If account_number = 112121 replace it by WALMART
>
> and if the account_number = 119435 replace it by SUPERMARKET

I tried to do it but i failed.

Can you help me?

Comment: Alright, so in order to remove the `LEFT JOIN` you’ll need to update your `DECODE` statement to use hard coded values instead of c.description. Remember to update the group by as well.

Comment: Hey dude!, how are you?
I have been playing with the query but i'm making mistakes; i mean, i need to hard-code the data from table clients (i dont want to use it anymore and i dont want to create another table)but i am destroying the logic behind :(. The query should return the account number and then, it should be replaced by the hardcoded value, i.e: 112121 replaced by WALMART. Can you help me?

Comment: @Del dude, how ar you? Could you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61220925/editing-the-output-set-brackets-depending-on-the-quantity-retrieved-and-the-sem?noredirect=1#comment108304129_61220925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert the value into the `prices_per_client` table directly, so you won't need this left join anymore.

---

or use a `case` statement in the select-section:

```sql
CREATE VIEW ppc_v AS 
SELECT ppc.*,
  CASE CUSTOMER_NUMBER 
    WHEN 112121 THEN 'WALMART' 
    WHEN 119435 THEN 'SUPERMARKET'
    ELSE NULL 
  END description 
FROM prices_per_client ppc
```

, create a `view` and apply it to the query:

```sql
SELECT '{"sku":"'||sub.item_code||'","PRICE":"'||sub.item_price||'",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:['||listagg('{"group":"'||sub.identifier||'","PRICE":"'||sub.price||'"}',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sub.identifier)||']};' AS JSON                                              
FROM (SELECT DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', ppc.description, ppc.customer_class_code) AS IDENTIFIER, tpp.item_code, replace(tpp.price, ',', '.') AS ITEM_PRICE, REPLACE(avg(ppc.price), ',', '.') AS PRICE, 
      tpl.request_id, max(tpl.request_id) over (partition by tpp.item_code) as max_request
      FROM table_price_list tpl
      INNER JOIN table_price_product tpp ON tpp.list_header_id = tpl.list_header_id AND tpp.request_id = tpl.request_id
      INNER JOIN ppc_v ppc ON tpp.item_code = ppc.item_code

      WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL(tpp.start_date_active, SYSDATE) AND NVL(tpp.end_date_active, SYSDATE+1)
      GROUP BY DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', ppc.description, ppc.customer_class_code), tpp.item_code, tpp.price, tpl.request_id) sub 
WHERE sub.identifier IS NOT NULL
and sub.request_id = sub.max_request
GROUP BY sub.item_code, sub.item_price;
```

Comment: Hey dude, how are you?
Thank you for replying!. Yeah, i thought about the CASE but when i tried to do that in my query it did not work

Comment: The problem is that i was not able to change my query using the CASE statement

Comment: strange, what error do you get?  at my desk the query is working fine.

Comment: How would you change my query? I need to modify my query.I know your code "works" but i cannot modify my code. Do you get me?

Comment: Dude, i am not supposed to create tables or views :/

Comment: then you have to replace each `description`by the complete 'case' statement