# Editing the output (set brackets depending on the quantity retrieved and the semicolon)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Every time that I run my code I obtain one, or two or several rows on a JSON format. I am using **Oracle 11g**.

This is my [CODE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e57ad6/58) on SQL Fiddle, you **will** find all the data there.

For example, in this case I obtained something like this:

> {"sku":"99342435","PRICE":"9999",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:[{"group":"A","PRICE":"29223"},{"group":"B","PRICE":"33223"},{"group":"SUPERMARKET","PRICE":"48343"},{"group":"WALMART","PRICE":"40340"}]};

BUT I could get this output depending on the data stored in the tables:

> {"sku":"99342435","PRICE":"9999",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:[{"group":"A","PRICE":"29223"},{"group":"B","PRICE":"33223"},{"group":"SUPERMARKET","PRICE":"48343"},{"group":"WALMART","PRICE":"40340"}]};
>
> {"sku":"95453343","PRICE":"8778",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:[{"group":"A","PRICE":"29223"},{"group":"B","PRICE":"33223"},{"group":"SUPERMARKET","PRICE":"48343"},{"group":"WALMART","PRICE":"40340"}]};

I want to make my query able to put an "open bracket" in the **first row**, check if there exist another rows and if no new rows are shown then, insert a **close bracket** in the end and a semicolon; something like this:

> **[**{"sku":"99342435","PRICE":"9999",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:[{"group":"A","PRICE":"29223"},{"group":"B","PRICE":"33223"},{"group":"SUPERMARKET","PRICE":"48343"},{"group":"WALMART","PRICE":"40340"}]}**];**

BUT another scenario could be when there exist **more than 1 row**; in that case I would like to put an **open bracket** in the first row but not a close bracket. I only want to open the bracket in the first row and close it in the last row and within, a semicolon. The different rows **MUST BE** separated by a **comma**. Please, follow this example:

> **[**{"sku":"99342435","PRICE":"9999",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:[{"group":"A","PRICE":"29223"},{"group":"B","PRICE":"33223"},{"group":"SUPERMARKET","PRICE":"48343"},{"group":"WALMART","PRICE":"40340"}]}**,**
>
> {"sku":"95453343","PRICE":"8778",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:[{"group":"A","PRICE":"29223"},{"group":"B","PRICE":"33223"},{"group":"SUPERMARKET","PRICE":"48343"},{"group":"WALMART","PRICE":"40340"}]}**];**

I tried so many times but I was not able to do it.

Can you help me?

Comment: Hey dude, how are you?. I've updated my question; yeah, it is a little tricky :/

Comment: Thanks for including the DBMS — I've also noted that the code is on SQL FIddle, but I think it should be in the question (the SELECT statement should be; the supporting data is fine on SQL Fiddle — say it is there).

Comment: Ready, thank you for the tips :). i think the best idea is to place everything inside SQL FIDDLE.

Comment: As I understand it, you're seeking to create a JSON 'object' when there's only one row to output (enclosed in `{ }`), and a JSON 'array' of objects when there's more than one row to output.  I suggest that always producing an array would be better — it can handle zero or more rows, each of which is an object.  I'm not clear why the semicolon is a good idea — it means it is no longer pure JSON.  I don't know what facilities Oracle provides for generating JSON from multiple rows of output; you can bash the manuals as well as I can.

Comment: Buddy, i could get more than 1 row to output; i need to get that weird format

Comment: See [Generation of JSON Data with SQL/JSON Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-6C3441E8-4F02-4E95-969C-BBCA6BDBBD9A) etc.

Comment: Yeah, i know that; i was trying to do some crazy stuff but Oracle and JSON are not good friends at all; anyway, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is starting to fall into the realm of just because you can make it work, doesn't mean you should.  But to answer your question, check this code out:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN sub2.TOTAL_ROW > 1 AND sub2.this_row = 1 THEN '[' ELSE NULL END||
       sub2.json||
       CASE WHEN sub2.total_row > 1 AND sub2.this_row = sub2.total_row THEN ']' ELSE NULL END AS JSON
FROM (SELECT '{"sku":"'||sub.item_code||'","PRICE":"'||sub.item_price||'",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:['||listagg('{"group":"'||sub.identifier||'","PRICE":"'||sub.price||'"}',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sub.identifier)||']};' AS JSON, 
      COUNT(*) OVER () AS TOTAL_ROW,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sub.item_code, sub.item_price) AS THIS_ROW                                         
      FROM (SELECT DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code) AS IDENTIFIER, tpp.item_code, replace(tpp.price, ',', '.') AS ITEM_PRICE, REPLACE(avg(ppc.price), ',', '.') AS PRICE, 
            tpl.request_id, max(tpl.request_id) over (partition by tpp.item_code) as max_request
            FROM table_price_list tpl
            INNER JOIN table_price_product tpp ON tpp.list_header_id = tpl.list_header_id AND tpp.request_id = tpl.request_id
            INNER JOIN prices_per_client ppc ON tpp.item_code = ppc.item_code
            LEFT JOIN clients c ON ppc.customer_number = c.account_number
            WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL(tpp.start_date_active, SYSDATE) AND NVL(tpp.end_date_active, SYSDATE+1)
            GROUP BY DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code), tpp.item_code, tpp.price, tpl.request_id) sub 
      WHERE sub.identifier IS NOT NULL
      and sub.request_id = sub.max_request
      GROUP BY sub.item_code, sub.item_price) sub2
ORDER BY sub2.this_row;
```

I updated your [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e57ad6/61/0)

What this query does is expand on the previous query.  It counts the total rows and this row using the analytic functions `COUNT` and `ROW_NUMBER`.  I didn't partition them at all because we want them to consider all returned rows.  If Total Rows > 1 and this is the first row start it with '['.  Append the JSON in the middle. And if this is the last row (Total > 1 and `ROW_NUMBER` = `COUNT`) then append ']' to the end.

**Edit 1: Changed to always have brackets**

```
SELECT DECODE(sub2.this_row, 1, '[', NULL)||
       sub2.json||
       DECODE(sub2.this_row, sub2.total_row, ']', NULL) AS JSON
FROM (SELECT '{"sku":"'||sub.item_code||'","PRICE":"'||sub.item_price||'",PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS:['||listagg('{"group":"'||sub.identifier||'","PRICE":"'||sub.price||'"}',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sub.identifier)||']};' AS JSON, 
      COUNT(*) OVER () AS TOTAL_ROW,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sub.item_code, sub.item_price) AS THIS_ROW                                         
      FROM (SELECT DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code) AS IDENTIFIER, tpp.item_code, replace(tpp.price, ',', '.') AS ITEM_PRICE, REPLACE(avg(ppc.price), ',', '.') AS PRICE, 
            tpl.request_id, max(tpl.request_id) over (partition by tpp.item_code) as max_request
            FROM table_price_list tpl
            INNER JOIN table_price_product tpp ON tpp.list_header_id = tpl.list_header_id AND tpp.request_id = tpl.request_id
            INNER JOIN prices_per_client ppc ON tpp.item_code = ppc.item_code
            LEFT JOIN clients c ON ppc.customer_number = c.account_number
            WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL(tpp.start_date_active, SYSDATE) AND NVL(tpp.end_date_active, SYSDATE+1)
            GROUP BY DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code), tpp.item_code, tpp.price, tpl.request_id) sub 
      WHERE sub.identifier IS NOT NULL
      and sub.request_id = sub.max_request
      GROUP BY sub.item_code, sub.item_price) sub2
ORDER BY sub2.this_row;
```

Here is the updated SQLFiddle ([Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e57ad6/62/0)).

Given the simpler logic, I switched out the `CASE` for `DECODE`.  IF the row is the first row it gets the opening bracket.  If it is the last row, it gets the closing bracket.  If it is both, it gets both.

Comment: Hey Del, how are you?. Thanks for replying. I do not know why but i find Oracle a little tricky; JSONs and everything related to that is weird and i get confused easily. They said: "come on, is not that difficult" and i just don't know. PS: You explain very well

Comment: Just a comment: it should display the open bracket '[' and the close bracket ']' always, the quantity of rows does not matter.

Comment: @Student_new I added an edit to fix the logic.  Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to deal with this is to do another `LISTAGG` over the results of your existing query and enclose that in `[` and `]`:

```
SELECT '[' || LISTAGG(JSON, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NULL) || ']' AS JSON
FROM (
  SELECT '{"sku":"'||sub.item_code||'","PRICE":"'||sub.item_price||'","PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS":['||listagg('{"group":"'||sub.identifier||'","PRICE":"'||sub.price||'"}',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sub.identifier)||']}' AS JSON                                              
  FROM (SELECT DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code) AS IDENTIFIER, tpp.item_code, replace(tpp.price, ',', '.') AS ITEM_PRICE, REPLACE(avg(ppc.price), ',', '.') AS PRICE, 
        tpl.request_id, max(tpl.request_id) over (partition by tpp.item_code) as max_request
        FROM table_price_list tpl
        INNER JOIN table_price_product tpp ON tpp.list_header_id = tpl.list_header_id AND tpp.request_id = tpl.request_id
        INNER JOIN prices_per_client ppc ON tpp.item_code = ppc.item_code
        LEFT JOIN clients c ON ppc.customer_number = c.account_number
        WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN NVL(tpp.start_date_active, SYSDATE) AND NVL(tpp.end_date_active, SYSDATE+1)
        GROUP BY DECODE(ppc.customer_class_code, 'E', c.description, ppc.customer_class_code), tpp.item_code, tpp.price, tpl.request_id) sub 
  WHERE sub.identifier IS NOT NULL
  and sub.request_id = sub.max_request
  GROUP BY sub.item_code, sub.item_price
) j
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9a86d/6)

Note that you need to enclose `PRICES_FOR_CLIENTS` in double quotes, otherwise the output of the query is not valid JSON. Also you need to remove the `;` from the end of the string output by the original query.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Nick.I'm checking this out!

Comment: @Student_new which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Actually I am using 11g but they are changing everything and 12c is coming soon

Comment: If you're using 11g you need to do it this way. Once you upgrade to 12c you'll have access to the JSON generation functions (JSON_OBJECT, JSON_ARRAY) and their aggregate versions and this will be *much* easier.

Comment: I'm new to Oracle database; some things are just "weird" to me :/